# Using this command in align* environment?

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, align, exam, examdesign

LaTeX newbie here. I am trying to create a mark scheme for an exam (pdfLaTeX). I have a command that writes the marks to a working step which works perfectly in display math mode:

```
\newcommand{\marks}[1]{\vadjust{\vbox to 0pt
       {
   \vss\hbox{\hskip\hsize\qquad\makebox [0pt][r]{[#1]}}
   \hrule height 0pt depth 0pt}}\ifmmode\else\vskip0pt\fi}
```

However, nothing happens when I try to use this command in the align* environment. Is there an alternative to the above command for it to work? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: The mathtools package provides a \mathmakebox command, along with \mathllap etc.  OTOH, I have no idea what #1 is supposed to be.

Comment: You can't define `\marks`.  That's a TeX primitive.